# How can I Electric Power, Water Wash soiled fruits and vegetables?

Tags: cooking

I'm physically unable to wash sullied ***TOUGH-SKINNED*** fruits and vegetables, particularly ones just plucked from soil. I'm disabled, and I injured myself. *The water pressure out of my faucets are TOO LOW AND POWERLESS to rinse off the dregs!*

**Please recommend any table top, electric powered, water jets or cleaners that can douse away the smut?** I hanker something that I can plug in my wall socket, and that has a removeable water tank that I can refill from my tap.  I live in the USA.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... also, your question is not really vegetarian specific ... meat eaters would also wash vegetables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can consider is replacing a faucet aerator with a device that narrows the diameter of the water stream coming from the faucet.

This will dramatically increase the pressure of the water, and likely make it sufficient to clean your fruits and vegetables.

I hope this helps you.